# How to Use Resque Web alongside a Sinatra app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, resque, resque-scheduler

I’ve got a Sinatra web app. I’m using Resque and Resque Scheduler, and now I’m looking into adding Resque Web to (hopefully) see what my Resque queue looks like. Now here’s my problem: the official [Resque Web](https://github.com/resque/resque-web) is a Rails app. I don’t know how to use a Rails app inside of Sinatra, or if it’s even possible.

So my question: What’s the best way to implement Resque Web into my Sinatra app? Can I use the rails app inside of Sinatra? I saw one person say that you should have a separate part of your app running Rails, but that seems really nasty. Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use the superior Sidekiq which uses Sinatra for the web interface. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring. It is much more lightweight than Resque and has scheduling built in, uses threads, more reliable.

Comment: No can do, unfortunately. Resque is already integrated into the app, and swapping it out would be more trouble than it’s worth.

Comment: What about this: https://github.com/defunkt/resque-web

Comment: @DamienRoche it looks rather abandoned to me. They didn’t even bother to make it into a gem, probably because everyone moved on to the official project. It might still be useable, but I kind of doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s what I was looking for: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/271-resque

Resque-web can be stand alone, run from the command line. So I’m just starting it up with a shell command whenever I spin up an instance of my server. Not exactly what I was looking for, but it does the trick!

Thanks for the suggestions, all.

Answer (score 2):

I've not used the ResqueWeb, but Rails and Sinatra are both Rack compliant frameworks, so they should be able to run each other or alongside.

http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Rack%20Middleware

```
## my-amazing-app.rb
use MySlightlyLessAmazingRailsApp
# rest of Sinatra stuff…
```

or

```
# config.ru
map "/" do
  # easiest to mount Sinatra apps this way if using the modular style
  run MyAmazingSinatraApp
end

map "/resque" do
  run MySlightlyLessAmazingRailsApp
end
```

I don't know how you'd do this with Rails, perhaps try this link http://m.onkey.org/rails-meets-sinatra or perhaps this:

```
RailsApp::Application.routes.draw do
  mount MyAmazingApp, :at => "/more-amazed"
  # rest of the rails routes
end
```

Comment: That link is the one I was talking about, which is something that I would prefer not to do. It seems really nasty to run Rails as well as Sinatra. Is that really the only way to do this?

Comment: @Timothy I actually split up a lot of my apps this way now - data only API, front end web app etc and then mount them all in the `config.ru` using `map`. It's one of the big reasons that Rack is so useful.

Comment: Really? huh. That’s interesting. Thanks for that insight. I’ll play around with this idea.